# Poor audio using AVAudioSession.Category.playAndRecord with CarPlay

Tags: ios, avaudiosession, recording, carplay

I'm building an app that is mostly around audio playback, but I occasionally want to record small bit from the microphone. I'm setting up my audio session like this:

```
try? AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.playAndRecord, 
   options: [.allowBluetoothA2DP]
)
```

When connected to bluetooth headphones, or via bluetooth audio to the car (a 2022 VW ID.4) this gives me the results I desire: playback is high quality via A2DP, and the recordings use the built-in iphone microphone.

However, when connected to CarPlay, the output audio quality suffers greatly; it sounds like it's using a bluetooth HFP connection.

Note that this only happens when using `.playAndRecord` -- if I setup the session with `.playback` the audio quality using carplay is just fine.

I've tried bludgeoning some workarounds like setting .playAndRecord at the last minute, or calling `setPreferredInput()` to force using the ios mic, but nothing seems to help.